# How to use the code to send SMS instead of sending emails in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, sms, email-validation

I'm beginner to vb.net and I'm using this code to send emails from my computer to others in my vb.net apps.
But now is it possible to use it to send sms instead to mobiles

```vb
Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("testemail@test.com", "xxxxxxxxxxx")
SmtpServer.Port = 25
SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.server.com"
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = False
Using mail As New MailMessage()
    mail.From = New MailAddress("testemail@test.com")
    mail.To.Add("94055999@txt.att.net")
    mail.Subject = "SMS Text Message"
    mail.Body = "Text Message Here ..."
    SmtpServer.Send(mail)
    MsgBox("Text Message sent successfully!")
End Using
```

Comment: I've written my own routines knowing what provider the recipient has.  It knows how to send to about 20 or 30 providers.  That said, it isn't optimal.  

The only solutions that I have found are 3rd party services or a software that requires a mobile phone to be connected to the server/desktop.

Comment: This is an opinion based answer but the solution is use is to install a 3rd party app on my phone called myMobKit and I used modified versions of the sample code. The sample code is c#, but telerik code converter does a reasonable job of converting it to VB

Comment: You posted your real username and password for the gmail account omanxp45@gmail.com! O.M.G.!